# Cordova iOS App Compilation with Zip plugin - aes/aes.h not found

Tags: c, xcode, cordova

I have a Cordova app fir iOS that I am trying to compile on Mojave. I am using XCode verision 10.2.1. The project is using the below versions of software. It worked on another computer that is running high sierra.

```
Cordova 6.3.1
npm 2.15.0
ios 4.2.0
```

When I load the project into XCode and compile, it fails with the below message on XCode.

`Lexical or Preprocessor issue. aes/aes.h file not found`

The location on the disk of the file above is `<proj_dir>/plugins/cordova-plugin-xip/src/ios/minizip/aes/aes.h`. The file that is including it is zip.c at `<proj_dir>/plugins/cordova-plugin-xip/src/ios/minizip/zip.c`

I have tried to modify search paths as suggested in some stackoverflow issues. I upgraded the platform ios within the project

I have also tried to remove and re-add the plugin `cordova-plugin-zip`
I have also ran the project in compatibility mode to different XCode version, still no go.
None of these have worked.

zip.c contents:

```
# include "aes/aes.h"
```

Error pointer is under folder aes. Unsure why the project cannot see the file that is at that location.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[cordova-plugin-zip](https://github.com/jjdltc/jjdltc-cordova-plugin-zip) contains [a podspec for `SSZipArchive`](https://github.com/jjdltc/jjdltc-cordova-plugin-zip/blob/master/plugin.xml#L48) which means you need to:

- have [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) installed and setup
- have Cocoapods repo up-to-date (`pod repo update`)
- open the `.xcworkspace` (not `.xcodeproj`) in Xcode to load the Pods project

Comment: I use the project generated by VS 2017. I copy it to a Mac and run the build from there. I did not install Cocoapods before, but it used to work. Is there anything else I can try because I use a new folder each time to build the project. Is that the best approach or do you reckon I do it differently???